# CSS: Use SVG image defined in markup (by #id)

Tags: css, svg

I have an svg defined in my markup

```
<html>
....
<svg id="my-svg">.....</svg>
....
</html>
```

is there a way to use this svg in CSS, e.g. as CSS background?

```
.a-div {
    background: url(#my-svg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do above is not possible. The closest possible solution would be to save the svg in its own file (e.g. `my-vector-image.svg`) and then use the following css:

```
.a-div {
  background: url(my-vector-image.svg);
}
```

You can read more about this [here](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-4).

Comment: I have the same image occurring at several places in a page with different colors. Any hint on how I can achive something like that?

Comment: I honestly think the easiest way to do that is to just create multiple svg files. It will unfortunately increase page load speed but hopefully if you run it through an svg optimizer/compresser it won't be that bad.